# interesting behaviour when using scanf on string with space in a loop

Tags: c, string, scanf

I was fiddling with C and happen to wrote code below. When I input a string with spaces, program receives all of the input but outputs them as if they were inputted as single words at different times. I thought scanf stopped when first whitespace character is encounterd and ignored the rest. But that seems, is not the case.

I included the output when I enter "inputWithNoSpaces" and "input with spaces", below.

I tried to look into stdin. It receives all the input. But I could not figure out what scanf was doing. I would like to learn what is happening.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char word[64]="";

    while(1)
    {
        printf("enter string:");
        scanf("%s",word);
        i++;
        printf("%d:%s\n\n",i,word);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
enter string:inputWithNoSpaces
1:inputWithNoSpaces

enter string:input with spaces
2:input

enter string:3:with

enter string:4:spaces

enter string:
```

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for string, use `fgets`.

Comment: Please be aware that stdio buffers whole lines of input. Scanf does not read from keyboard; it reads from that buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `scanf()`, `"%s"` means "skip whitespace characters then read a sequence of non-whitespace characters". So when you give it the input `input with spaces` it will return `"input"`, `"with"` and `"spaces"` in three sequential calls. That is the expected behavior. For more information read the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man3/scanf.3.html).

```
input with spaces
^^^^^                    First scanf("%s", s) reads this
     ^                   Second scanf("%s", s) skips over this whitespace
      ^^^^               Second scanf("%s", s) reads this
          ^              Third scanf("%s", s) skips over this whitespace
           ^^^^^^        Third scanf("%s", s) reads this
```